# Como retornar apenas o nome do arquivo do path?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, diretório

Como retornar o valor com o nome de uma pasta em C#?

Exemplo, se executo:

```
Directory.GetFiles("%PROGRAMFILES% (x86)\MyApp", "*.*", true);
```

E se conseguir executar ele retorna assim:

```
%PROGRAMFILES% (x86)\MyApp\MyApp.exe
%PROGRAMFILES% (x86)\MyApp\MyApp.dll
```

E o que eu quero é só retornar no lugar de MyApp apenas `\`.

Ex: `\MyApp.exe` ou `\MyApp.dll`, em vez do caminho ao diretório completo.

Comment: Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Use o [`Path.GetFileName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_IO_Path_GetFileName_System_String_).

```
var nomeArquivo = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Tente isto:

```
var arquivos = Directory.EnumerateFiles("%PROGRAMFILES% (x86)\MyApp", "*",
                   SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(Path.GetFileName);
```

Eu tenho minhas dúvidas se esta pesquisa é o que você quer, mas fiz como foi apresentado.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kPMdgy). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MisuA3). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetPath.cs).

Comment: essa pesquisa é relacionado a um sistema de cópia de arquivos tipo um instalador que eu estou desenvolvendo.

Comment: OBS: Directory.EnumerateFiles não encontrado.

Comment: Não sei o que isto quer dizer. Está querendo me informar que dá algum erro? Dê mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.IO;
    // manipular de diretorios
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Documents and Settings\etc\etc ");

    // procurar arquivos
    BuscaArquivos(dirInfo);

private void BuscaArquivos(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
     // lista arquivos do diretorio corrente
     foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    {                
           // aqui no caso estou guardando o nome completo do arquivo em em controle ListBox
           // voce faz como quiser
           lbxResultado.Items.Add(file.FullName);                
    }

    // busca arquivos do proximo sub-diretorio
    foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
          BuscaArquivos(subDir);
    }
}
```