# Retornar um valor parecido da path

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo

[Sem resultado nesse meu post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89296/retornar-o-valor-da-path), eu gostaria de saber como seria utilizado a função `Directory.GetFiles`, para listar os arquivos e pastas dentro da mesma sem mostrar o caminho completo.

Ex:

```
public List Listar(String a){
    return Directory.GetFiles(a, "* .*").ToList();
}
```

static void Main(string[] args){
    var lista = Listar(@"C:\Windows\Inf");
    foreach(string a in lista){
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Exit();
}

> Nesse contexto deveria retornar em vez de **C:\Windows\Inf\arquivo.inf** retornaria apenas o arquivo: **\arquivo.inf** o mesmo seria com as pastas.
>
> > Ex: Existe uma pasta com o nome de **arquivos0** ele retornaria em vez de **C:\Windows\Inf\arquivos0\** apenas **\arquivos\**

OBS: Me disseram o seguinte:
Executar:

```
var arquivos = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\Windows\Inf", "*",
                   SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(Path.GetFileName);
```

> mas quero executar esse código e o Visual C# 2008/2010 diz que a referência: `Directory.EnumerateFiles` não existe pois utilizo apenas a versão 4.0 do Microsoft .NET Framework

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi bem a pergunta, você quer recuperar apenas o nome do arquivo? nome dos arquivos de uma determinada pasta?

Comment: O método [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) existe no .Net 4.0. Tem de referenciar o *mscorlib assembly* e declarar `using System.IO;`

Comment: Ah sim! por isso não consigo ver o `Directory.EnumerateFiles`. Pensei que essa função se aplicava ao .NET 3.5 Muito obrigado @ramaral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente, você não conseguiu usar [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) porque não deve ter importado o namespace `System.IO`, pois ele funciona sim no .NET Framework 4.0.

Essa solução pega todos os arquivos dentro de determinada pasta e dentro de todas subpastas, mostrando apenas o nome do arquivo no console. Se você quiser pegar apenas do diretório principal, mude o terceiro parâmetro de `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` de [`SearchOption.AllDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx) para [`SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx).

Existem outras maneiras de fazer isso, mas acho que essa já soluciona teu problema de uma forma bem simples e prática.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO; //Importe este namespace para usar Directory.EnumerateFiles()

namespace TesteArquivos
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lista = Listar(@"E:\Teste");

            foreach (string a in lista)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> Listar(string caminho)
        {
            var arquivos = Directory.EnumerateFiles(caminho, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(Path.GetFileName);

            return arquivos;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

***Use uma classe assim:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Dir
    {
        public string DirPath { get; private set; }
        public Dir(string Path)
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path)) throw new FormatException("Caminho inválido");
            DirPath = Path;
        }

        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string[], string[]>> GetItems()
        {
            char separator = char.Parse("\\");
            foreach(string _dir in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(DirPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                var name = _dir.Split(separator).Last();
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string[], string[]>(new string[2] { _dir, name }, 
                    System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_dir), "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                    .Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x))
                    .ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Como usar:***

```
Dir _dir = new Dir(@"D:\Temp\php");

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string[], string[]>> itens = _dir.GetItems();

foreach(KeyValuePair<string[], string[]> item in itens)
{
    string PathFull = item.Key[0]; // nome completo da pasta
    string namePath = item.Key[1]; // somente o nome da pasta
    System.Console.WriteLine("Pasta: {0}", namePath);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Files");
    foreach (string files in item.Value)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", files); //somente o nome do arquivo
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine("");
    System.Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");
    System.Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

***Exemplo de saída:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]